# How to display a chart which has larger dataset in a dashboard widget?

Tags: charts, dashboard, widget

I have a dashboard which display different charts as equal sized widgets.The issue with my current UI is when there is more data labels and data sets the charts looks compressed.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]
Is there a better way to handle the multiple data labels/data sets in charts.

Comment: are these labels interactive? also how is the chart interactive over all? Can i click on / off to filter the labels (remove visibility from the chart)?

Comment: Yes the labels are interactive has on/off , on click of a label the selected data alone will be show in chart

Answer (score 2):

#### Try showing the 5 top total counts by make, and allow them a drilldown (or expand the chart in place) for further examination.

There comes a point of overload where you're showing everything, but they're seeing very little.

Since this is a dashboard, a common pattern is to show the top 3 -7 of a category.
You can start with top 5, so the chart is uncluttered, and have a high enough color contrast set so it's easy to pick out:

[image]